# How to render text on path?

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to write curved text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8337221/how-to-write-curved-text)

I want to render text as in given image (in place of "AMEX 3"). Please tell me how to achieve this.

[image: Image with the text "AMEX 3" inside a curved arrow]

Comment: Probably some IMP was used to make this picture: "A", "M" and "E" chars are out of alignement. Anyway Jave's one is the answer.

Answer (score 12):

Create a round [Path](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Path.html) - object, and then in a custom canvas use [drawTextOnPath](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawTextOnPath%28java.lang.String,%20android.graphics.Path,%20float,%20float,%20android.graphics.Paint%29).

```
Path path = new Path();
path.addCircle(x, y, radius, Path.Direction.CW);
myCanvas.drawTextOnPath(myText, path, offset, 0, myPaint);
```

myCanvas should now contain the curved text.