# How to write curved text?

Tags: android

I want to write curved text like this:

[image: curved text]

How can I do this?

Answer (score 35):

Lol, this is fun, I've just tried to make a text curve, you can try it:

```
package pete.android.study;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Path;

import android.graphics.RectF;
import android.view.View;

public class GraphicsView extends View {
    private static final String MY_TEXT = "xjaphx: Draw Text on Curve";
    private Path mArc;

    private Paint mPaintText;

    public GraphicsView(Context context) {
      super(context);     

      mArc = new Path();
      RectF oval = new RectF(50,100,200,250);;
      mArc.addArc(oval, -180, 200);          
      mPaintText = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
      mPaintText.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
      mPaintText.setColor(Color.WHITE);
      mPaintText.setTextSize(20f);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
      canvas.drawTextOnPath(MY_TEXT, mArc, 0, 20, mPaintText);      
      invalidate();
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like you want to [draw text on a path](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawTextOnPath%28java.lang.String,%20android.graphics.Path,%20float,%20float,%20android.graphics.Paint%29). Therefore you should [create a path that is an Arc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Path.html#addArc%28android.graphics.RectF,%20float,%20float%29) and then draw the text on it and that should work perfectly. I hope that helps.

Comment: But i m not having x, y......what to do?