# Curved text on outside of path

Tags: android

How should I go about drawing text along a curved path, but facing out rather than in? I found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8337221/how-to-write-curved-text) on drawing text to a curve and it' the method I currently use, but the text is unreadable when upside down(at the bottom of a circle). Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up drawing a path using quadTo() and then rotating the canvas 180 degrees about the curve to draw it correctly. Felt like a bit too much effort for something that should be natively supported by drawtextonpath()...

Answer (score 0):

Indeed there's a simpler way to achieve that, it's suffice to pass a **negative** sweep angle in the `addArc` method, and the arc will be drawn counter clock-wise :)