# Putting dynamic numbers on a shape in android

Tags: android, shapes

**What I want:**

> I want to create shapes (shapes can be rectangle, circle or any) and
>   put some random numbers to that shape.

**What I've done:**

> I've already created shapes using custom view.

**Problem:**

> How to put random numbers on shapes dynamically?

**Note: position of numbers should be different each time you open app.**

my code for drawing a shape is :

```
package com.example.myb.bazibadast;


import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;

public class YeknafareActivity_layout extends View {

Paint black_paintbrushstroke;
Path Hand;


public YeknafareActivity_layout(Context context) {
    super(context);

}


@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);


    black_paintbrushstroke = new Paint();
    black_paintbrushstroke.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    black_paintbrushstroke.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    black_paintbrushstroke.setStrokeWidth(4);


    Hand = new Path();
    Hand.moveTo(225, 844);  // A
    Hand.lineTo(191, 675);

    Hand.moveTo(191, 675);  // B
    Hand.lineTo(114, 412);

    Hand.moveTo(114, 412); // C
    Hand.lineTo(147, 409);

    Hand.moveTo(147, 409); // D
    Hand.lineTo(235, 591);

    Hand.moveTo(235, 591); // E
    Hand.lineTo(179, 279);

    Hand.moveTo(179, 279); // F
    Hand.lineTo(222, 279);

    Hand.moveTo(222, 279); // G
    Hand.lineTo(300, 534);

    Hand.moveTo(300, 534); // H
    Hand.lineTo(308, 186);

    Hand.moveTo(308, 186); // I
    Hand.lineTo(341, 187);

    Hand.moveTo(341, 187); // J
    Hand.lineTo(382, 513);

    Hand.moveTo(382, 513); // K
    Hand.lineTo(427, 212);

    Hand.moveTo(427, 212); // L
    Hand.lineTo(460, 216);

    Hand.moveTo(460, 216); // M
    Hand.lineTo(462, 536);

    Hand.moveTo(462, 536); // O
    Hand.lineTo(476, 613);

    Hand.moveTo(476, 613); // P
    Hand.lineTo(507, 662);

    Hand.moveTo(507, 662); // Q
    Hand.lineTo(593, 501);

    Hand.moveTo(593, 501); // R
    Hand.lineTo(628, 492);

    Hand.moveTo(628, 492); // S
    Hand.lineTo(645, 511);

    Hand.moveTo(645, 511); // T
    Hand.lineTo(470, 960);

    Hand.moveTo(470, 960); // U
    Hand.lineTo(386, 989);

    Hand.moveTo(386, 989); // V
    Hand.lineTo(280, 947);

    Hand.lineTo(225, 844);


    canvas.drawPath(Hand, black_paintbrushstroke);
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by `How can I tell the android that inserts numbers dynamically inside of the shape?`?

Comment: @JRG I mean What code should I put in my app? and Where? (in my activity or my custom view class?)

Comment: Show some code/algorithm what you have tried so far... Had you searched you could have find this https://stackoverflow.com/a/8309003/2700586

Comment: @Mani I'm new in Android, man. I've searched but I didn't find any solution.
and the page that you mentioned isn't what I want. it's something different.
I don't have any idea that how should do this. I just draw a shape & now I want to put numbers from 0 to 100 inside of shape in random positions.for each time you play an app.
sorry for my bad English ;)

Comment: `"I just draw a shape & now I want to ..."` - how do you draw it?

Comment: @pskink I edit my question with the code of drawing a shape.

Comment: then now use `Canvas#drawText`

Comment: @pskink thanks , I'll try that. really appreciate

Comment: @pskink Can you Please guide more & tell me what exactly code should I use? 
thank you

Comment: whats ubclear with `drawText`? it takes only 4 parameters: text, xpos, ypos and paint

Comment: @pskink drawText is ok, but my problem is: How to put random numbers on shapes dynamically?
Should I use Random? or something else.
I have no idea about this!!!

Comment: yes use `Random`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those, who have the same problem as I did, in below link I get an answer that solved the problem in another way. however, I've changed that answer a little to match what I need.
so if you have the same problem please check the answer in below link:

[how to create array of numbers in range 1 to 100 in view class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45692378/how-to-create-array-of-numbers-in-range-1-to-100-in-view-class)